# Android - TranslateAnimations

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

When I try to apply a translate animation on an `ImageView`, the image just completely disappears. I am not sure why this would happen because I ran this code through the eclipse debugger and the value for the x_start and x_final seem to be correct.

Any ideas on why this would be happening or how I can end up getting my `TranslateAnimation` to work?

```
    chargeButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
            int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

            switch (event.getActionMasked()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    chargeButton.setLayoutParams(setPosition(x_cord, false));
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    int x_start = x_cord;
                    x_cord = 0;
                    slowMove(x_start, x_cord, false);
                    chargeButton.setLayoutParams(setPosition(x_cord, false));

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });


}

public void slowMove(int x_start, int x_final, boolean pay)
{
    Animation transAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(x_start, x_final, 0, 0);
    transAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    transAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    if (pay)
        payButton.startAnimation(transAnimation);
    else
    {
        chargeButton.clearAnimation();
        chargeButton.startAnimation(transAnimation);
    }
}
```

A little more background, this function is being called from an `onTouchListener` under the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` case.

I **feel as though I need to use Animation.Relative_TO_SELF** or something like that for the positioning. However, I am not sure how to do that when I **only have the absoute positioning** of the ImageViews.

Any and all ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please provide more code details.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the layout parameters to move your views - it is really not a good idea. I have been down that road and nothing good came out of it.

Consider extending View and setup your own custom view where you can have full control of what goes on.

Comment: Finally I found out why it isn't working, thank you! +1